# Not able to get error object in JSON format while using @Valid and MessageSource to get display errors in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, validation

I am currently learning Spring REST and I am trying to build a demo spring boot app. Incase of DTO object has validation error I want to show it as below:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "first_error_code",
      "message": "1st error message"
      "field":"field_name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where the *code* in above JSON should display the validation message that I have given in my entity class i.e

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{name.not.empty}")
    String name;
```

then **code should be name.not.empty** and message should be taken from messages.properties file.

Now to achieve this, I used several tutorials. Below are the classes:

Main class: (Included MessageSource and LocalValidatorFactoryBean)

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableSwagger2
   public class Demo3PathvariableApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Bean
        public MessageSource messageSource() {
            ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
            messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
            messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            return messageSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(MessageSource messageSource) {
            LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
            bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
            return bean;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Demo3PathvariableApplication.class, args);
        }

        /*
         * To enable matrix variables, configurePathMatch() method of WebMvcConfigurer
         * needs to overriden. Matrix variables are disabled by default and the
         * following configuration
         * 
         * urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
         * 
         * should be present in the overriden method to enable the same. see below
         * method.
         */

        @Override
        public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
            UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
            urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
            configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
        }

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST");
        }

        /* For Swagger Document Generation */
        @Bean
        public Docket api() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.infytel.controller")).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
                    .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
            // To scan for RestControllers from this package and For disabling default
            // response messages
        }

    }
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
@Api(value = "CustomerController, REST APIs that deal with Customer DTO")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity createCustomer(@RequestBody @Valid CustomerDTO customer, Errors errors) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.createCustomer(customer));

    }
}
```

FieldErrorDTO.java:

```
    public class FieldErrorDTO {

        private String errorCode;
        private String message;
        private String field;

        public FieldErrorDTO(String errorCode, String message, String field) {
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
            this.message = message;
            this.field = field;
        }
//Getter setter
```

ValidationErrorDTO.java:

```
public class ValidationErrorDTO {

    private List<FieldErrorDTO> fieldErrors = new ArrayList<>();

    public ValidationErrorDTO() {
        super();
    }

    public void addFieldError(String errorCode, String message, String field) {
        FieldErrorDTO error = new FieldErrorDTO(errorCode, message, field);
        fieldErrors.add(error);
    }

    public List<FieldErrorDTO> getFieldErrors() {
        return fieldErrors;
    }

    public void setFieldErrors(List<FieldErrorDTO> fieldErrors) {
        this.fieldErrors = fieldErrors;
    }

}
```

RestErrorHandler .java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ValidationErrorDTO processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<org.springframework.validation.FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
        return processFieldErrors(fieldErrors);
    }

    private ValidationErrorDTO processFieldErrors(List<FieldError> fieldErrors) {
        ValidationErrorDTO dto = new ValidationErrorDTO();
        for (FieldError fieldError : fieldErrors) {
            String localizedErrorMessage = resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(fieldError);
            dto.addFieldError(fieldError.getCode(), localizedErrorMessage, fieldError.getField());
        }

        return dto;
    }

    private String resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(FieldError fieldError) {
        Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String localizedErrorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, currentLocale);

        return localizedErrorMessage;
    }

}
```

messages.properties

```
name.not.empty=Please provide a name.
email.not.valid=Please provide valid email id.
age.adult.only=Age should be more than 18.
```

Now with all these config, I am able to see below JSON,

```
{
    "fieldErrors": [
        {
            "errorCode": "NotEmpty",
            "message": "Please provide a name.",
            "field": "name"
        },
        {
            "errorCode": "Email",
            "message": "Please provide valid email id.",
            "field": "email"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I acheive this requirement, where instead of "errorCode": "NotEmpty", I want show

```
 "errorCode": "name.not.empty"
```

From CustomerDTO class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you need to change you processFieldErrors:

First remove "{}" from your anotations:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "name.not.empty")
String name;
```

Second:

```
private ValidationErrorDTO processFieldErrors(List<FieldError> fieldErrors) {
        ValidationErrorDTO dto = new ValidationErrorDTO();
        for (FieldError fieldError : fieldErrors) {
            String localizedErrorMessage = resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(fieldError);
            dto.addFieldError(fieldError.getDefaultMessage(), localizedErrorMessage, fieldError.getField());
        }

        return dto;
    }
```

And third, change your message.getMessage:

```
private String resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(FieldError fieldError) {
        Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String localizedErrorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError.getDefaultMessage(), null, currentLocale);

        return localizedErrorMessage;
    }
```

This way you would retrieve the key for the message. In your example it will be :

```
name.not.empty
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this already. This results in {
            "errorCode": "Age should be more than 18.",
            "message": "Age should be more than 18.",
            "field": "age"
        },
errorCode and message becomes same.

Comment: I haved added more details for the workaround. Hope it helps